# Get C/C++ project support back with MonoDevelop 4.0 a.k.a. Xamarin Studio

Tags: c++, c, project, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

With the latest Xamarin Studio (relabeled from MonoDevelop 4.0), I cannot open `.cproj` projects anymore that worked in MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7.

The [feature list](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Feature_List) says it's not supported on Windows but it also says "Page last modified 09:53, 27 Oct 2010"…

Is there a way to re-add the language binding? Do I need to recompile myself? Maybe there is a mirror of old MonoDevelop binaries for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ has never been supported in MonoDevelop on Windows, though reportedly some users were able to get it working with a mingw32 environment. Unfortunately the addin was accidentally included in some of the MonoDevelop 3.0.x releases for Windows.

You could in theory just copy the C/C++ addin dll from a Mac/Linux machine, or build it from source on Windows, and drop it into your Xamarin Studio installation. And if you contribute fixes to make it work well on Windows it will be shipped in future XS releases :)

Comment: Right, I wrongly assumed it works out of the box on Windows when I was actually using Linux all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you can add support to Xamarin Studio 4.0, but if you'd like to use an older version of MonoDevelop, binaries are available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/monodevelop.mirror/files/