# how to add a c/ c++ compiler in monodevelop?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, monodevelop

I am using Monodevelop for unity3d on windows 8 machine. I came to know that I can create a C /C++ project in Monodevelop But when I do not getting a C/C++ option on new solution window when i want to create a new project in C/C++. the options are only Boo, C#, Unity Script and VBnet. Do I need to install external C /C++ compiler on my machine? Also will I be able to write OpenGL Programs with monodevelop?
Thank you

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057041/get-c-c-project-support-back-with-monodevelop-4-0-a-k-a-xamarin-studio) for c/c++ mono support, and for developing  OpenGL program with mono, have a look at [OpenTK](https://github.com/mono/opentk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C/C++ plugin of MonoDevelop is only compatible with non-Windows platforms for now.

It's [opensource](https://github.com/mhutch/cbinding), so if you have time, you're welcome to fix this situation.